# Why does Google create abbreviations for methods in their Javascript code?

Tags: javascript

This is an example of what I am talking about. Doesn't this just make it more complicated, or is that the point?

```
var ga = "appendChild",
        ha = "shift",
        ia = "exec",
        ja = "width",
        s = "replace",
        ka = "concat",
        la = "charAt",
        ma = "match",
```

**EDIT:**

This is where I found the code.

https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js

Comment: Is this an unminified version of the Google Analytics tracker? If not, please link to the source.

Comment: This is minified code, probably with closure compiler

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minification_(programming)

Comment: Does the linked code look handwritten to you?

Comment: now you can say "kalama" instead of "concatcharAtmatch"!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google is simply minifying their JS files. There are two main reasons to minify: bandwidth savings and lower TCP round trips.

Bandwidth Savings:
    Minifying a file can more than halve its size. So bandwidth savings are a given.

TCP Round Trips:
    I'm not going to go into too much detail about TCP round trips (read [Even Faster Web Sites](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596522304) by Steve Souders). JS files in the head of a page are extremely important. JS files can block the rest of the page's assets from being downloaded. Minifying the page allows for less round trips. Platform JS could transfer with as little as 2 round trips. The standard version could take an upwards of 6 round trips.

In short, minifying is a smart thing to do. It's very difficult to edit minified files. So, be sure to edit the original file, minify the file and then upload them to your server. In addition to minifying JS, you should consider minifying your HTML and CSS as well.

Javascript/CSS: 
[YUI Compressor](http://yui.github.io/yuicompressor/)

HTML:
[PageSpeed Insights](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights_extensions)